# SQL Syntax and Columns using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, facebook, syntax

(This is called via PHP) I have the following:

```
"SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2={$user})"
```

The SQL executes perfectly fine, however, the result is an array where the key is "name".  I would like each result's key to be the respective `uid` in `user` that was searched to pull that name.

**Example:**

*How it is right now*

If the `name` was "Bob" and his `uid` was "12345", I would like the return array to be - `[name] => Bob`.

*How I would like it to be*

If the `name` was "Bob" and his `uid` was "12345", I would like the return array to be - `[12345] => Bob`.

EDIT (as per the comment request):

```
$fql = "SELECT pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2={$user})";
        $param = array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql,
            'callback' => ''
        );
$result = $facebook->api($param);
```

Comment: Show us some code. How are you executing the query? What does this have to do with Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newResult = array();
foreach ($result as $entry)
{
    $newResult[$entry['uid']] = $entry['name'];
}
```